# Workarounds to implement interface including <TIn extends T>, with X[] type parameter

Tags: java, generics, contravariance

Let's say we have some interface like this:

```
public interface Foo<T> {

   <TIn extends T> void encode(TIn value)

   T decode()

}
```

I'm using Foo a lot in my codebase, but I wish to add the `TIn extends T` to make it more flexible, to eg have a `Foo<Map<X>>` able to `encode` a `HashMap<X>` or a `TreeMap<X>`.

This works really well - until I tried to implement `Foo<T[]>`, where it seems to be impossible to implement, with `public <TIn extends TItem[]> void encode(TIn array)` giving a parse error "`> expected`" when it hits the brackets `[]`. Even IntelliJ does nothing when it volunteers to implement the interface.

For what it's worth, if T is some other concrete final type (eg byte[], Boolean, etc), it seems that I can satisfy the interface by just returning T, so it seems to do some hidden intelligent fixing here. So it seems that it's just a problem with `T[]` where it can't detect `T[]` is final.

Does anyone have any ideas about how I can workaround this? I don't really care that `TIn extends byte[]` can only be met with `TIn = byte[]`, I just want to implement the interface for the compiler to be happy; and so that this interface can be used elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of this makes sense. You don't *need* that `TIn` in the first place:

```
public interface Foo<T> {
  void encode(T value);
  T decode;
}

class Example {
  void test() {
    Foo<HashMap<String, Integer>> foo = null;
    foo.encode(new HashMap<String, Integer>());
  }
}
```

This compiles just fine. In general if you declare a new typevar that is used in only 1 place, it's pointless - typevars are solely a thing `javac` worries about, the runtime doesn't know what generics (typevars) are. Hence, it doesn't make much sense to use them unless they serve to link 2 different places where a type is mentioned, e.g. 'the type of parameter to the encode method, the return type of the decode() method? I don't care what it is, but, for any given usage of the `Foo` type, it's the same - that kind of 'linking').

Given that there's no need to introduce an additional type param on the `encode` method, there's no need to try to declare a new type var there.

The usual alternative to a typevar that is used in just a single location is `?`. There is no functional difference between `<F> void foo(List<F> in)` and `void foo(List<?> in)`.

Comment: hahaha oh damn, so true. I'm having one of those days where I'm overcomplicating simple things. void encode(T value); can take any subclass of T, by definition. Thank you! :).